# Draw more attention to "Step 2: Publish question" box, or skip it

Tags: feature-request

I just posted a question for the first time in a while, and when I hit the submit button - which I only now realise is labelled "Review your question", all that *seemed* to happen was that the page scrolled back to the top with no discernible change.

After a puzzled moment I noticed that the box on the right - which I hadn't even noticed while typing - had changed to show "Step 2: review" or something to that effect, and text that the automated system had found no problems.

If the automated system found no issues with my question, why not just... publish it? Why do I have to scroll all the way down again to hit Submit a second time if all is well?

I'm going to hazard a hopeful guess that when something *is* detected as being problematic with my question, then the box will be highlighted in some way to draw attention to the problem. But as it is, I was very confused about the unnecessary extra step of "clicking the Submit button twice".

Comment: a funniest thing is that you can  *review* the question, get the OK and you can keep editing later and then publish! you don't need to review a second time.

Comment: This is a useful feature. It prevents accidental submission and makes the poster take a second look at their question.

Comment: Related post on Uber Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347679/why-do-i-have-to-click-twice-to-submit-a-question-when-stack-exchanges-automate